# How is airliner pressurization being coped with at high altitude airports?

Tags: airliner, cabin-pressure, high-altitude

Cabin altitude in a passenger airliner must not become more than 8,000 ft, but what if an airliner flies to or from an airport at a higher elevation, such as Quito and La Paz? How is onboard pressure regulated when more pressure is required onboard than there is outside?

Most likely the cabin altitude is adapted eventually, but at what point of flight?